# Unnest list of strings to single string

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame with a list of strings in one column. I am trying to use `unnest_tokens` on that column, to have one token per row, but am unable to do so when the strings are in a list.

The data frame looks like:

```
> dat
 department instructor_gender                                            comments
1        BME                 F is amazing and you will love her!, Prof. is so nice
```

I've tried to unnest using

```
dat.word <- dat %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, unlist(comments))
```

but get:

```
Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.
```

How can I unnest this list of strings, to have one word per row?

**Edit:**

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(department = "BME", instructor_gender = "F", comments = list(
    c("is amazing and you will love her!", "Prof. is so nice"
    ))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

**Edit 2: desired output**

```
> output
     word department instructor_gender
1      is        BME                 F
2 amazing        BME                 F
3     and        BME                 F
4     you        BME                 F
```

Comment: Show the `dput` for the `dat`.

Comment: No problem. I've added it.

Comment: Do you want the line to be one string? Or all comments to be merged into one string? Can you give the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `tidyr::unnest` before :

```
df <- structure(list(department = "BME", instructor_gender = "F", comments = list(
  c("is amazing and you will love her!", "Prof. is so nice"
  ))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% unnest %>% unnest_tokens(word, comments)
#     department instructor_gender    word
# 1          BME                 F      is
# 1.1        BME                 F amazing
# 1.2        BME                 F     and
# 1.3        BME                 F     you
# 1.4        BME                 F    will
# 1.5        BME                 F    love
# 1.6        BME                 F     her
# 2          BME                 F    prof
# 2.1        BME                 F      is
# 2.2        BME                 F      so
# 2.3        BME                 F    nice
```

You error said:

> Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character 
>   vectors, each of which has a length of 1

You fed it a list of one character vector of length 2.

Basically you can feed it a string, or a vector/list containing only strings.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! What did adding `unnest` do there?

Comment: @Adam_G See my edit, let me know if something's unclear